# sass if even number in for loop

Tags: for-loop, sass, increment

I'm trying to do something very simple and can't seem to do it, and it's driving me crazy.  I want to tell if I number is even, and increment a variable by one.  This is what I've been trying:

```
@for $i from 1 through 6 {
    $rgba-opacity:0.5;
    &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
        background: rgba($color-white-primary, $rgba-opacity);
    }
    @if #{$i} % 2 == 0 {
        $rgba-opacity: $rgba-opacity+0.5;
    }
}
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is child one and two, get one color value, child three and four get another, and child five and six get a third.  Any idea's on why this isn't working?  Thanks so much for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code (assuming you have pasted the complete code), you are using `&:nth-child()` directly which will give an error `Base-level rules cannot contain the parent-selector-referencing character '&'.` You need to specify a parent selector for it.

```
$r : 100;
$g : 120;
$b : 140;
$rgba-opacity:0.5;

@for $i from 1 through 6 {  
  div {
    &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
     background: rgba($r, $g, $b, $rgba-opacity);
     &:before {
      content: ""+$i;
     }
    }
  }
  @if $i % 2 == 0 {  //use $i for calculating mod here than #{$i}
   $rgba-opacity: $rgba-opacity + 0.2;
   $r: $r + 100;
   $g: $g + 100;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Output:

[image]

[Demo here](http://codepen.io/anpsmn/pen/raMYOW)

Comment: thanks so much for taking the time to explain this, I really appreciate it.  Just learning this and sometimes you just need a nudge or concept explained.